# How to freely drag and drop elements on IntelliJ IDEA GUI designer for Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

Whenever I create a new GUI Form, all the base layout manager types I select have some sort of grid or alignment. How can I make it so that I can drag the buttons, textboxes, etc freely without grids?

I'm no way knowledged in Java and am just poking around to see if I can get along with it as an additional language.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this still applies 
[IntelliJ: How to use No Layout or Absolute Layout like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642449/intellij-how-to-use-no-layout-or-absolute-layout-like-eclipse)

Layout managers in swing has some sort of boundaries that they work with. As far as i have read in the docs the GUI-builder aims to mimic their behaviours (haven't used it myself). It's better to learn how they work instead to position your components properly.

Read up on the managers and their behaviour here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, IntelliJ does not support Null or Absolute layouts but you can install the [JFormDesigner plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/274-jformdesigner) which has support for GridBagLayout, MigLayout, and GroupLayout (this is the one you'd be interested in). This is a paid plugin.

The top-level Jpanel has a [Layout Manager property](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/populating-your-gui-form.html) that defaults to what you have selected in you GUI Designer settings.

[image]