# How to use No Layout or Absolute Layout like Eclipse?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, intellij-idea

Title says all I would like to use no layout or the absolute layout from Eclipse. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern GUI design. You don't control factors like fonts and font metrics, dpi and/or differences in rendering pipelines that will change the individual requirements of components. Swing has been designed to operate with layout managers, removing them can not only result in inflexible but may not longer update correctly through various API calls you are typically use to. Null layouts may seem like a good idea when you start, but as your UI becomes more complex, they require much more attention that can reduce your time on actual developing the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

It's not supported in IntelliJ. Why don't you want to use a `LayoutManager`?

Source: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/3537347?tstart=0

---

If you use absolute layout, you have to do resizing entirely yourself, making sure things are lined up (which could be deep inside nested containers) by yourself, etc.

Check out `GroupLayout`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html

Comment: I don't want to use a layout manager because it makes weird vertical and horizontal lines that mass up the spacing and placement of my objects, if there is a way around this please let me know!

Comment: @TheCodingTraceur post a **different** question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of that problem!

Comment: This is the problem with some software ... Developer want to use solution X, the IDE tells him, no use Y instead ?! I want to resize everything my self and I have my own reasons. in addition this is something offered by Java . Intellij wants to be a java IDE right ?